# Apache Require not ip isn't allowing me to restart httpd

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm running Apache 2.4 and am trying to block an IP address from my webserver, it's a Cent OS 8 server and I'm editing my `httpd.conf` file, but for some reason when trying to block an IP and restart httpd, I get a FAILURE exit code.

What am I missing?

```
#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/var/www/MY-SITE/dist"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    <RequireAll>
      Require all granted
      Require not ip X.X.X.X
    </RequireAll>

    # Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

Erorrs I get after simply adding:

> Require not ip X.X.X.X

is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is X.X.X.X a valid IP there?

Comment: `X.X.X.X` is a mere use of privacy, the actual IP address has been added, this is just for Stackoverflow

Comment: I know that. But is the real Ip address correctly mentioned?

Comment: show exact error line

Comment: @Exampleperson attached error screenshots. And yes, IP is correct. It's: `
5.39.190.244` which is perfectly valid.

Comment: @ExamplepersonI'm trying to block requests to my server, why would adding `Require not ip 5.39.190.244` fail to restart httpd after running the restart command

Comment: What does a simple `apachectl configtest` tell you?

Comment: Or in other words: did you see the second line in the screenshot you posted? Where it tells you where you can get additional information? So what _did_ you learn by that?

Comment: And, just by the way: that error message does not match what you claim you added. The error message refers to an enclosing `<RequireAny>` block, the code you posted shows a `<RequireAll>` block.

Comment: @RyanH the first one should work right?

Comment: Remove the RequireAny

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447).