# Require not ip isn't blocking IP address on apache centos server

Tags: apache, centos, httpd.conf

I'm trying to block an IP from my server and prevent them from being able to load my website, I've added their IP to the `httpd.conf` file and have successfully restarted httpd, but after trying to load the website, I'm still able to access the website, surely I'm not missing something obvious here am I?

What am I doing wrong?

```
#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/var/www/MY-SITE/dist"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    <RequireAll>
      Require all granted
      Require not ip X.X.X.X
    </RequireAll>

    # Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Require not ip isn't allowing me to restart httpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345268/apache-require-not-ip-isnt-allowing-me-to-restart-httpd) It looks like a rephrased question that you asked just before this one.

Comment: Atleast delete that question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In here

```
<Directory "/var/www">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
<RequireAll>
  Require all granted
  Require not ip X.X.X.X
</RequireAll>

# Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

you need to change Directory path like this

```
<Directory "/var/www/MY-SITE/dist">
```

then try it. thnak you